# Density plot of probabilities

Tags: probability, logistic, density-function

I have created a density plot with ggplot for the predictions of Logistic regression (probabilities). [image]

I do not understand the y - axis. Why the range is not 0-1?

Comment: Are you asking why the probability density is not in $[0, 1], $ is it?

Comment: Yes! It seems that it is 0-10

Comment: On the y axis you read the estimated densities, not probabilities.

Comment: The area under the density should be 1. If the probability is focused in a narrow range the height must be large, or the area would be less than 1. e.g. consider a uniform distribution on (0, 0.1) -- what must the height be? Many questions on site already cover this issue in some detail